# OpenAI Fine-Tuning error - 'fileName contains an invalid filename: wrong suffix.'

Tags: openai-api, fine-tuning, azure-openai

I am trying to fine-tune a GPT model through the Azure OpenAI API.

I now need to upload the file to openai using the code below:

```
file_name = "training_data_prepared.jsonl"

upload_response = openai.File.create(
  file=open(file_name, "rb"),
  purpose='fine-tune')

upload_response
```

However, when I run the code now, I get the following error:

```
InvalidRequestError: fileName contains an invalid filename: wrong suffix.
```

Everything is set up correctly on the API side, and I have converted a csv to jsonl using the 'openai tools fine_tunes.prepare_data' command and it correctly created the jsonl file. The configuration of the json file should be correct, and follows the openai guidelines for creating a fine-tuning dataset.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue, but i added one more parameter and it works for me. the parameter was

```
training_response = openai.File.create(
    file=open(training_file_name, "r"), purpose="fine-tune",user_provided_filename=training_file_name
)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEkAR.png)

Comment: this helped resolve the suffix issue, thank you! however, now getting ``ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai.object_classes'`` and searching didn't return relevant results for that module...thoughts?